# Django 2+ : Optional URL using PATH, without making multiple URL

Tags: python, django, url

i have this url

```
path('<slug>/thank_you/<user_id>', thank_you, name='thank_you'),
```

i want the `<user_id>` to be optional, but i dont want to make 2 urls like this

```
path('<slug>/thank_you', thank_you, name='thank_you'),
path('<slug>/thank_you/<user_id>', thank_you, name='thank_you2'),
```

i understand that you can make it optional using regex, but thats if you're using django <2 (using url, not path)

how do i obtain this ?

Comment: I think it is not possible based on the docs [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/urls/#how-django-processes-a-request)

Comment: To that kind of cases use re_path instead of path. Then in your view user_id has to be optional parameter like: my_view(request, slug, user_id=None)

Comment: @Mikey you are right, but OP mentioned `i want the <user_id> to be optional, but i dont want to make 2 urls like this `

Answer (score 0):

You can use [**`URL Query String`**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) for this. For example:

```
# URL
path('/thank_you/', thank_you, name='thank_you'),

# View
def thank_you(request, slug):
    user_id = request.GET.get('from')
    # rest of the code

# Example route
http://localhost:8000/dummy-slug/thank_you/?from=dummy_user_id
```

Comment: thanks for your answer, the reason why i want to show the user_id is to trace which and how many user have gone through the previous page. i use google analytics, and it wont detect `http://localhost:8000/dummy-slug/thank_you?<user_id>` . it has to be a proper link `http://localhost:8000/dummy-slug/thank_you/<user_id>`. can you trace user_id using this method ?

Comment: Can you share your code for google analytics? because you should be able to send querystring parameters with google analytics.

Comment: unfortunately i dont have the access to the google analytics code, it is handled by the higher-ups. i'll try your method first, thank you :)